# Finding a monotonically increasing sequence of integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to find a monotonically increasing sequence of integers, the sequence should be increasing as slow as possible and it has couple of additional requirements:

1. $n_{i+1} \gt n_i$
2. $n_{i} + n_{j+1} \gt n_{i+1} + n_{j}$ where $i+1 < j$

As an example we may consider a sequence of positive integers.

$$
\left\{
n
\right\}^{4}_{n=1}
$$

If $i=1$ and $j=3$, $1+4 = 2+3$ which violates 2nd requirement.
The best what I was able to find so far is Fibonacci sequence which seems to work for both requirements if $i \ge 2$.

Comment: Since you point out that the sequence should be monotonically increasing, 1. should be $n_{i+1} > n_i$, I think. Also, I'm not sure what 'the sequence with the smallest memory consumption' means.

Comment: @Ruben You are right, fixed, thanks.

Comment: @Ruben The smaller amount of bytes it takes to store finite sequence the better it's in terms of memory consumption.

Comment: If you are looking for a finite sequence you could just look at an empty sequence. So I assume you are looking for an infinite sequence that increases, but as slowly as possible? Also, the second requirement is probably easier to understand if you write it as $n_{i + 1} - n_i \not = n_{j+1} - n_j $. I would expect $i < j$ or $i \not = \ j$ here as a condition, are you sure this is right?

Comment: @Ruben Yes, you are correct, infinite sequence, but it may be increased by $0.00000001$ which is slower than increasing by $1$, but takes more bytes to store. I've corrected 2nd requirement a bit. With $i + 1 < j$ I want to make sure, that there is no "overlapping" between $(i, i+1)$ and $(j, j+1)$.

Comment: You should clarify your question. Specifically, you need to specify which encoding you are using (or if you are free to pick any encoding), and you need to define 'the smallest memory consumption' more precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I interpret the "smallest memory" as a sequence that as many terms can be stored for a given memory size as possible. In other words, the sequence should be increasing as slow as possible while meeting the requirements. The OP is further 'implying' that (yeah, this question is really not clear at all) a step size smaller than 1 may take more memory, which means that he is thinking to store data in integer type, not in floating point.

As the sequence should meet $$a_n > a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-3},$$ the slowest sequence will be $$a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}-a_{n-3}+1$$
So $a_0,a_1,a_2\dots$ will be:
$$0,1,2,4,6,9,12,16,20,25,30,36,42\cdots$$
And it is observed that the steps are:
$$1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6\cdots$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
&a_{n}-a_{n-1}=\lfloor \frac {n+1}2\rfloor, \quad \text{or}\\
&a_{2n}-a_{2n-1}=n\\
&a_{2n+1}-a_{2n}=n+1\\
&a_{2n}-a_{2n-2}=2n\\
&a_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^n2k=n(n+1)\\
&a_{2n+1}=n(n+1)+n+1=(n+1)^2\\
\end{align}
Or, simply
$$a_n=\lfloor\frac {n+1}2\rfloor\lfloor\frac {n+2}2\rfloor$$
To check if this sequence meets your 2nd requirements (obviously it is increasing so it meets the 1st requirement), if
$$j>i+1 \rightarrow j\ge i+2$$
then
$$a_{j+1}-a_j=\lfloor \frac {j+2}2\rfloor>a_{i+1}-a_i=\lfloor \frac {i+2}2\rfloor$$

Comment: I've thought of this answer as well, but you can't represent an infinite sequence that goes to infinity with the usual integer representations, so technically this answer is not correct (not your fault, because the current form of the question is technically not answerable).